# Why git push notification number increases for a single commit in SourceTree if I took pull after commit

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

**The MRE:**

1. Have SourceTree configurated with our codebase.
2. You should be at least 1 commit behind the remote repository of our CodeBase.
3. Don't take a pull, directly commit any file.
4. You will see `1` notified in the git push button in ST.
5. Now, take a pull.
6. Notice that the number changes to `2` in the git push button.

Can someone please tell me why?
Does that number represent no. of commits, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The pull has likely resulted in a merge commit, merging the local changes you had with the 1 remote change.

```
--------------L local
--------------R  remote
```

After pull

```
--------------LM local
               /
--------------R  remote
```

You are now 2 commits (LM) ahead of the remote, your original change + the merge with remote. Even though your contents are now synced with the remote.

An alternative would be to do a pull-rebase, that will rewrite your local history to replay your changes on the remote:

```
---------------L local
--------------R  remote
```

After pull-rebase:

```
--------------RN local
--------------R  remote
```

L will be rewritten to have R as a parent instead and will result in a new local commit (N).